# Where should I redirect after filling a "creation" form?

Tags: usability, forms, user-expectation, design-patterns

HI hope y'all doing well

I have an app where users need to create different items.

There's a page that displays all the items created that as a "*Create new...*" button.

---

The user's path:

1. User goes to the "all items" page.
2. Clicks on "*Create new...*" button.
3. Complete a form.
4. Click save.
5. ...

---

Where should the user be directed after?

I've found 2 possible options:

- Some argue that the user should go back to where he came from *i.e.* "all items" page.
- Some say the user should be directed to the "newly added item" page.

Is there a solution better than the other?

Thanks :)

**[Edit]** by "newly added item" I mean a different page than the one where the user completed the form. See the screenshot below.

Should the user follow the dashed purple line or the red dotted line after the click on the "save" button?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what will likely happen next. If the user will want to keep working on the newly added item (let's say they're writing an article, and want to keep editing a draft), they'll stay on the Newly Added Item page. If they're more likely to want to add more new items, they should be taken back to the All Items page so they can click the Create New button again.

Either way, they'll need a little confirmation message telling them that their newest item has been created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Izquierdo,
The "newly added item" is not editable, so to do some modification the user will need to click on an "edit" button. I've edited my question and added a screenshot of the user's path.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshots. Is there anything (user research) that would lead you to believe that the user would want to edit that information right after creating it? If not, it's probably the better bet to return to the All Items page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
No, not really. I'll go with your proposition.
Thank you for your time. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

@Izquierdo's answer is quite reasonable. But if you still not sure what user prefer to do after entering data into the form let him decide himself by adding one more action button:

<kbd>SAVE</kbd> <kbd>SAVE AND EDIT</kbd> <kbd>CANCEL</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Serg
My main concern is where the user should be directed after the "save" button is clicked. The options are to the "all list items" page or the page of the created item, which is not editable. 
Having a "save & edit" button doesn't really help me in this case. If the user clicks on the "save & edit", my guess is that he will stay on the same page so I still need to figure out on what page the "save" will direct him to.
Thanks for your time, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something succinct. Probably like the following:

<kbd>Save | +</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>

Here, `Save` part is for saving and going back to whatever would be more natural for specific case. Say, in you case it could be the same list of items, if there are actions other than just creating new items.

The vertical bar `|` part is not clickable and is for visual separation.

The `+` part is for saving the current item and starting creating a new one.

For an example implementation, check, say, Google Docs. Create a new document or open an existing one and see how <kbd>100% | v</kbd> is done.

Finally, the <kbd>X</kbd> is for cancelling the current item and returning to the list of items or other meaningful location.